# Сервер golang не отвечает при частых запросах к БД?

Tags: mysql, golang

Есть функция для работы с БД

```
    db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "", "test")

    err := db.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")
    }

    rows, _, err := db.Query(Query,args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос",Query,err)
    }

    return rows
```

Если идёт большое количество запросов-(на самом деле их можно 'наклацать' мышкой скажем со скоростью 10-15 в секунду) переходит в обработчик-'Не удалось подкл и выполнить запрос' и всё приложение висит около минуты.
После этого по непонятным причинам опять всё работает.
err написал  read tcp 127.0.0.1:20673->127.0.0.1:3306: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
Подскажите пожалуйста- в чём тут дело и что можно сделать?

Comment: походу дело было в defer db.Close()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всегда при работе с пакетом `database/sql` необходимо следить за открытыми ресурсами. В вашем случае вы оставили незакрытым подключение к БД (`db`) и строки `rows`.

`sql.Rows` держит подключение из connection pool’а открытым до тех пор, пока вы не пройдете по ним всем при помощи `rows.Next()` или пока вручную не закроете подключение методом `rows.Close()`.

Когда вы 10-15 раз “наклацали” подключений, то, вероятнее всего, уперлись в полоток максимально открытых подключений со стороны сервера MySQL. Проверьте его настройки.

Видимо, внешний код, который вызывает вашу функцию итерируется по строками (`rows`) и по окончанию прохода автоматически высвобождает подключение к БД.

В качестве решения я бы предложил:

1. Переписать функцию так, чтобы обработка строк проходила внутри нее и возвращать не `sql.Rows`, а какой-то обработанный результат. Тогда можно будет написать в функции

`defer db.Close()
defer rows.Close()`

и все будет работать отлично

2. Во внешнем коде правильно обрабатывать закрытие `sql.Rows`.

Хороший материал по работа с БД в Golang можно почитать вот [здесь](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/).

Comment: Да-я понял. Там накосячил и соединение не закрывалось. Спасибо